# Out of memory error thrown when using to read S3 object using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, out-of-memory, netty, boto3

Using boto3 to read an object throws out of memory error-

org.python.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 2080374784, max: 2092957696) in  at line number 407

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
csv_obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, key).get(Range= 'bytes=0-2048')
```

Comment: Is it from lambda?

Comment: @Marcin No , its used directly in script

Comment: Where is running then? On your local workstation or on AWS?

Comment: @Marcin On a tomcat server